# How to make a secure login page, search functions

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I would like to know how can I make a secure login page? I don't want to add a register page I just want to login with just a username and password ( administration panel ) , but I don't know how to secure it . I'm using defult Login from toolbox.

Also I would like to know how to make a search function I will add a image to show .example[image: This is the example]

Would someone don't mind helping me ? 
PS: sql database 2008

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use forms authentication.

The below link will help you a lot:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb

it also allows you to map the users from database and add roles to them and it is secure as login cookies are encrypted and it also gives you the flexibility for the way you want to modify it.

it also allows you to specify access to folders.
the above link will make thing clear for you and will be helpful

and for search : Use sql stored procedures with params with normal select statement in it

Answer (score 1):

You can use [forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx) and add credentials directly to the `forms` element in your web.config. That way you don't need any database backend.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e01fc50a.aspx

It's not super secure, but as long as nobody has access to your web config it's OK, especially if you just store the SHA1 hash and not a password in clear text. You can encrypt the respective configuration section in addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want simple authentication, you should investigate FormsAuthentication. Using this you can exclude part of your application from being secured.

Comment: I'm not so good at asp.net if you don't mind show me some tutorials thanks

Comment: Search Google for "FormsAuthentication tutorial". You can use Google right?

Comment: Ok , what about the search?that's really important for me , and I couldn't find a way to make it.